# ¿Puedo crear una clase dentro de un método?

Tags: php, poo, clase

Estoy con Laravel, y cuando creo un controlador `php artisan make:controller usersController -r` se me crean varios métodos, cada método hace una acción específica única para cada página, ahí mi problema.. quiero realizar peticiones AJAX aprovechando estos métodos, pero cuando la lógica se vuelve grande la programación estructurada se vuelve confuza e insostenible..

**La pregunta es:** ¿Puedo crear una clase dentro de un método? ¿PHP me permite hacer esto? y si es asi.. ¿Estoy rompiendo el paradigma y estoy realizando una mala practica?

los estoy leyendo gracias

Comment: Las clases son contenedores de métodos y no al revés, lo que buscas realizar no tiene mucho sentido, si tu controlador se vuelve grande y la lógica extensa entonces lo que deberías hacer es mover la lógica a otra capa y luego solo usar esa lógica llamandola en tu controlador

Comment: se que es una pregunta muy vaga, pero no la he encontrado en internet, realmente busque y nada

Comment: @BetaM Lo pensé así, pero tengo me surge otro problema, tengo 50 controladores(miento, 54) para una pequeña pagina, si no me crees mando foto

Comment: El número de controladores (*aunque extenso para una pequeña página*) no termina de ser relevante, como te dije no es lógico pensar en declarar clases dentro de métodos, lo mas simple serái crear otras capas, toma como ejemplo el propio Laravel, tiene en una capa por separado a los middlewares y no importa cuantos tengas, cuando los requieres solo los invocas

Comment: @BetaM Uh bueno.. por lo visto no me queda de otra, haré eso entonces, muchas gracias por responder rapido